# How can I use arrays within objects?

Tags: php, oop

I was making a class in PHP for validation of a contact form, when I hit a problem. I eventually tracked it down to an array within the class, and wrote a test script to try to solve the problem:

```
<?php

class Object {
    public $testArray = array(5);

    function __construct() {
        $testArray[] = 7;
    }

    function addNumber() {
        $testArray[] = mt_rand(10,20);
    }

    function returnArray() {
        return var_dump($testArray);
    }
}

$object = new Object;
$object->addNumber();
echo($object->returnArray());
var_dump($object->testArray);
```

This outputs `NULL array(1) { [0]=> int(5) }`.

I am confused as to why this does not work. Eventually I would like the array to be private, but I can't find a way similar to `get` and `set` in C#. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use `$this` keyword for accessing the properties and methods of the class.

Comment: In some other languages, you can use the variable names directly, in PHP you need to access them via `$this`. That is independent to private, protected or public. This has been asked before but is perhaps hard to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
class Object {
    public $testArray = array(5);

    function __construct() {
        $this->testArray[] = 7;
    }

    function addNumber() {
        $this->testArray[] = mt_rand(10,20);
    }

    function returnArray() {
        return var_dump($this->testArray);
    }
}
```

You have to reference the class variable using $this - otherwise it'll try to set a variable local to the function you're in.

You can use PHP's magic __set() and __get() methods for similar functions to C# that you mentioned: [PHP Overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
$testArray[] = mt_rand(10,20);
```

Should be:

```
$this->testArray[] = mt_rand(10,20);
```

`$testArray` is just another local variable (local to the function, no the class). If it has no value it is `null`. This is consistent with the output you're seeing. `$object->testArray` is never modified.

Answer (score 1):

You have to access class variables using $this. So $testArray should be $this- >testArray.